# Can we integrate WebAPI (written in VB) using .NET Framework 4.7.1 with OWIN?

Tags: azure-active-directory, owin

Can we integrate WebAPI (written in VB) using .NET Framework 4.7.1 with OWIN?

I can find references to do the same with C# but not for WebAPI written in VB.